# Select categorical variables where number of levels is equal to 1

Tags: r, apply, sapply, data-cleaning

Doing pre-processing in Data Mining sometimes involve re-grouping and re-coding categorical variables. It is well known that once you recode categorical variables in R (i.e. function `mapvalues`) you need to update your categorical variable with `df$variable <- factor(df$variable)` so that you can view the real number of levels in your data.frame with `str(df)`.

I have written a piece of code to update automatically the categorical variables of a dataset:

```
cat <- sapply(df, is.factor) #Select categorical variables
names(df[ ,cat]) #View which are they
A <- function(x) factor(x) #Create function for "apply"
df[ ,cat] <- data.frame(apply(df[ ,cat],2, A)) #Run apply function
str(df) #Check
```

My question is: how could I select columns whose number of levels is equal to 1, once I have updated my dataset? I have tried these lines without luck:

```
cat <- sapply(df, is.factor) #Select categorical variables
categorical <- df[,cat] #Create a df named "categorical" separating them
A <- function(x) nlevels(x)==1 #Create "A" function for apply
x <- data.frame(apply(categorical,2, A)) #Run apply function
utils::View(x) #Check and see it is not working...
```

I appreciate your help and time

Comment: May be `indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels)==1; df[,cat][,indx]`

Comment: Nice! I thought about `length(levels())`

Comment: @akrun Your line works perfectly. Thank you very much for your response. It returns a logical with TRUE/FALSE depending it's a 1 level categorical variable or not. I will tag it as correct answer.

Comment: I posted that as a solution.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a logical index with `sapply` and use that to filter out the columns.  The reason

```
  indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels)==1
  df[,cat][,indx, drop=FALSE]
```

Or another option is `Filter`

```
 Filter(function(x) nlevels(x)==1, df[,cat])
```

Or

```
 Filter(Negate(var), df[,cat])
```

---

Regarding why the `apply` didn't work,

```
 apply(df[cat], 2, nlevels)
 # V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 
 # 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

the output is `0` for all the columns, so something is not correct.  Upon further checking

```
 apply(df[cat], 2, class)
 #       V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6 
 #"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" 
 #       V7          V8          V9         V10 
 #"character" "character" "character" "character"
```

And the correct `class` can be found from

```
 sapply(df[cat], class)
 #    V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8 
 #"factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" 
 #    V9      V10 
 #"factor" "factor"
```

The `class` of the columns got changed from 'factor' to 'character' because the output of `apply` is a `matrix` and a `matrix` can hold only a single class.  If there is any non-numeric column, it will convert the whole matrix columns to 'character' class.  You can use `apply` for a `numeric` matrix as the the return class will be also 'numeric.  In general, when there are mixed class columns, it is better to use `lapply/vapply` and to get a logical vector or so `sapply` is also useful.

#### data

```
set.seed(64)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 3*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=10))

df <- cbind(df, V11=1:3)
cat <- sapply(df, is.factor)
```

Comment: `indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels)==1` here it is saying that there is no closure of brackets

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor that is a strange error as I don't see any issue ini that code

Comment: pls see my answer below, for the issue im facing

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor I get `indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels)==1;
> indx
   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: I have a dataframe which is named as train_1. 
I am trying to find out categorical variables which have levels > 2 

    `indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2)`
    `df[,cat][,indx, drop=FALSE]`

Error: 
       `indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2)`
       `Error in match.fun(FUN) :` 
      'nlevels(df[, cat]) > 2' is not a function, character or symbol
      > df[,cat][,indx, drop=FALSE]`
      `Error in `[.data.frame`(df[, cat], , indx, drop = FALSE) :` 
      `object 'indx' not found`

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor can you please check the comment below your answer

Answer (score 1):

I have a dataframe which is named as train_1. 
1. I am trying to find out the categorical variables which have levels > 2 and less than 20 lets say.
2. Categorical variables which have levels > 2

**Find out categorical variables**

```
cat <- sapply(train_1, is.factor) #Select categorical variables
```

**Levels >2**

```
indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2)
df[,cat][,indx, drop=FALSE]
```

**Error:**

```
   indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2)
   Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'nlevels(df[, cat]) > 2' is not a function, character or symbol
  > df[,cat][,indx, drop=FALSE]
  Error in `[.data.frame`(df[, cat], , indx, drop = FALSE) : 
  object 'indx' not found


   >cat
    Store     DayOfWeek          Date         Sales     Customers 
    FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE 
     Open         Promo  StateHoliday SchoolHoliday 
     TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE 

     filter1<-Filter(function(x) nlevels(x)>2, df[,cat])
     head(filter1)
   StateHoliday
1               0
1116            0
2231            0
3346            0
4461            0
5576            0
```

There are so many categorical variables in my cat, but this output is strange. Open, Promo columns are not there for eg

Comment: In your code the last `)` is out of balance i.e. `sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2)` instead it should be `sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2`

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in:
`"indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2
indx"`

Comment: any library that could be missing?

Comment: No, it is just the `)` at the end that is creating the issue.  You dont need that `)` after the 2

Comment: Can you just correct the `)` at the end `indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels(df[,cat])>2)`

Comment: Okay, now, i understandn the issue, .why you are changing the `nlevels` to `nlevels(df[,cat]`.  It is just `indx <- sapply(df[,cat], nlevels) > 2` sorry, didn't see your df[,cat' earlier

Comment: Here the `sapply` is looping over the columns and you just need `nlevels` to apply to that column